# Command name for Collapse All,Expand All Nodes in XML Editor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

What is a command name for keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio (I use 2012) to collapse/expand all nodes in XML Editor window?

Comment: If you know the shortcut you can see the matching command in Tools - Options - Environment - Keyboard.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Its `Edit.ExpandAllOutlining` and `Edit.CollapseAllOutlining` i think.

See Menu `Edit->Outlining` in Visual Studio. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td6a5x4s.aspx)´s the reference from MSDN

> - Hide Selection
>     *(CTRL + M , CTRL + H) - Collapses a selected block of code that would not normally be available for outlining, for example an if block. To
>     remove the custom region, use Stop Hiding Current (or CTRL + M, CTRL +
>     U). Not available in Visual Basic.*
> - Toggle Outlining Expansion    *Reverses the current hidden or expanded state of the innermost outlining section when the cursor lies
>     in a nested collapsed section.*
> - Toggle All Outlining
>     *(CTRL + M, CTRL + L) - Sets all regions to the same collapsed or expanded state. If some regions are expanded and some collapsed, then
>     the collapsed regions are expanded.*
> - Stop Outlining
>     *(CTRL + M, CTRL + P) - Removes all outlining information for the entire document.*
> - Stop Hiding Current
>     *(CTRL + M, CTRL + U) - Removes the outlining information for the currently selected user-defined region. Not available in Visual
>     Basic.*
> - Collapse to Definitions
>     *(CTRL + M, CTRL + O) - Collapses the members of all types.*

Comment: `Ctrl+M, Ctrl+L` is what I was looking for at that time

Answer (score 29):

From `Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard->mapping scheme (Default)`

- Expand all: CTRL + M, CTRL + X
- Collapse all: CTRL + M, CTRL + A

For selected areas:

- Expand selection: CTRL + M, CTRL + E
- Collapse selection: CTRL + M, CTRL + S